# C#/.NET Use of unassigned local variable when used with out parameter and null-coalescing operator

Tags: c#, .net

I've come to situation, where I'm using null-coalescing operator and on both sides I'm calling method. Left side of operator is invoked and if the result of cast is null, then the right side is invoked. On both sides it invokes method, which sets the value via `out` parameter. The value of `result1` variable should always be set (even if it is null).

When I'm doing standard assign of value (via equals `=` sign), compiler / VS don't yell.

**Question**: why does compiler/VS show an error CS0165, when the value have to be always set to something?

After downvotes, I'm coming to pinpoint specifics of this question:

- I know that `string result1 = null` solves the error, I'm not asking for that.
- In right part of code (`?? <there>`), I'm not using null-conditional (`?.`) operator. That implies only 2 possibilities to happen: **Method invoked and value is assigned** OR **`NullReferenceException` is thrown**.

Sample of the code:

```cs
public class A 
{
    public string Get() { return "A"; }
    public string GetOut(out string result) { result = "A"; return "A"; }
}

public class B 
{
    public string Get() { return "B"; }
    public string GetOut(out string result) { result = "B"; return "B"; }
}

var a = new A();
var b = new B();

var test = (object)a;
string result1;
string result2 = (test as A)?.GetOut(out result1) ?? (test as B).GetOut(out result1);
string result3 = (test as A)?.Get() ?? (test as B)?.Get();
string result4;
(test as A).GetOut(out result4);

// ERROR on this line: CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'result1'
if (result1 == null) { } 

if (result2 == null) { } // Is OK
if (result3 == null) { } // Is OK
if (result4 == null) { } // Is OK
```

Comment: `string result1 = null;` !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: No it's not.  If `test` is neither A nor B, `result1` will never be set. Your code intentionally hides the type of the variable by casting to object. What are you trying to achieve with such code?

Comment: At *runtime*. At compile time the compiler *knows* that the type of `test` is unknown, and it's perfectly possible for it to be neither A nor B. Again, what are you trying to achieve with such code?

Comment: Besides what does `when I'm calling right side` mean? Whose right side? The assignment's? `??` ? If `test` was a class C, or a number, `GetOut` would never be called. `result1` would never get a value. The compiler knows that, so it throws an error. You really are trying to access a variable that may not be assigned

Comment: You keep repeating what happens at runtime. The compiler doesn't deal with the runtime. Besides, what you claim isn't true. What if `GetOut` was an extension method that ignored nulls? The compiler works with what it knows at *compile time*. With what it knows, `result1` can easily remain unassigned

Comment: I've removed previous comments & put them to question. @PanagiotisKanavos I'm trying check for certain type and if it is, invoke its method. If its not the type, go for another. Only specific of this is that the value assignment is done via method with `out` parameter.

Comment: If. you want to check for a specific type there are far easier ways. Besides,  you *remove* the type information by the cast to `object`. Are you really trying to solve a real problem or testing edge cases?

Comment: Besides, the fact that the code may throw an exception at runtime doesn't affect the compiler at all. That's why NRTs were added in C# 8, to make it clear that some reference parameters and variables can never be null

Comment: Real case, I've just simplified code for better understanding. I'm surprised by compiler's behaviour since all the "logical paths" are covered. Answer from D Stanley makes little more sense. To your last comment, if you add this row `(test as A).GetOut(out result1)`, the error is gone. Compiler understands that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler just isn't sophisticated enough to know that `result` *should* be initialized in all circumstances. Your code is equivalent to:

```
        string result1;
        string result2;
        var temp = test as A;
        if (temp != null)
            result2 = temp.GetOut(out result1);
        else
            result2 = null;
        if (result2 == null)
            result2 = (test as B).GetOut(out result1);
```

So the compiler would have to examine these branches to know that *logically*, if `test` is not an `A`, then `result2` will be `null`, and in that case, the second `if` will be executed, which means that `result1` *will* be initialized.  That much logic just isn't built into the compiler at this point.

Or, possibly, there *is* some condition in which `result` would not be initialized, and I'm not seeing it.

Your best bet is just to initialize `result1` to `null` and move on.

Or, change you assignment to the slightly more verbose:

```
string result2 = (test is A) ? (test as A).GetOut(out result1) : (test as B).GetOut(out result1);
```

That removes the second `if` from the equivalent code and makes the assignment definite

Comment: I believe Eric Lippert has an article about this and how they decided to end static analysis of this kind at a certain level instead of trying to get it perfect, to keep the code base clean and easier to work with. The reasoning was that you almost never hit this limit and when you do all you need to do is initialize your temporary variable.

Comment: @Blindy by any chance, do you know if it was published online or do I need to look somewhere else? Cheers :)

Comment: I'm like 80% sure it was on his blog, https://ericlippert.com/, but I didn't find this specifically from a quick search.

Comment: @Blindy: Me neither! I think you and I are both remembering a post on this site rather than a blog article, but I have not yet transferred all my old blog content from MSDN to my own site.

Comment: But your point is completely correct. The specification has clear and relatively simple rules which determine when a variable is definitely assigned; though it does some tracking of Boolean truth and falsity for `if` statement conditions, it does not do as good a job at tracking Boolean-equivalent conditions such as nullity. There are proposals to make the compiler's typing rules more flow-sensitive in light of recent non-nullity tracking work but I do not know the status of those proposals.

Comment: Incidentally, when I was at Coverity we had a number of very interesting "false path pruner" algorithms which would attempt to analyze situations like the one presented here, where it looks like there are many paths through a program but in fact only a few of them are "truly possible" paths. We tried pruners for situations involving not just nullity but also more advanced Boolean properties such as "this collection is empty/not empty" and that sort of thing.

Comment: One could search the site for `user:88656 unassigned` and browse through some of the interesting (and mostly related) answers.